# white-space: nowrap causing error in lighthouse

Tags: lighthouse

Anyone else having issues with lighthouse in chrome dev tools giving error report when using

`white-space: nowrap;`

If I remove the line in my css **`white-space: nowrap;`** lighthouse works again.
Here is the error report I get with the line white-space: nowrap;
[image]

Comment: do you have the complete CSS selector that contains this, seems like an interesting bug you have found. What is the URL you were testing?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to correct the error by changing this:

```
.text-truncate {
     overflow:      hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space:   nowrap;
}
```

to:

```
.text-truncate {
     overflow:      hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space:   nowrap;
     clip:          rect(0 0 0 0);
     clip-path:     inset(0%); 
}
```

Comment: Hello Ana, welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer seems not to fit to the question?